# SnappyData or SnappySession: SignalHandler: received explicit OS signal SIGPIPE

Tags: snappydata

Get this error when sending data to the cluster:

> 2018-01-22 18:49:54 101 4859929 [SIGPIPE handler] WARN  snappystore - SignalHandler: received explicit OS signal SIGPIPE
>   java.lang.Throwable: null
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.SigThreadDumpHandler.handle(SigThreadDumpHandler.java:112)
>           at sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:212)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 2):

This means that there has been an unclean socket close on a receiver/sender so the OS has sent a SIGPIPE. Not a problem itself but could indicate some problem on the connection to a remote node. Usually happens when network connectivity to a remote node is down in the middle of operation or remote node has gone down abruptly. I would see the logs before and after to see if any exception was received from a remote node and then go check that node.